# Not getting the updated shared preferences value in real time

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, dart

Below is the code to get the Image from the gallery or camera. The setter function for the sharedPreferences have been defined in another class. Here I am trying to get the image and have defined the getter for shared preferences. I am able to get the image but I am unable to get the image in real time or instantly. i am just able to get the update image once I navigate to another page.

```
 File? _imageFile;
  late Future<File?> _imageFuture;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _imageFuture = showData();
      }

  Future<File?> showData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final base64Image = prefs.getString('myImageKey');
    if (base64Image != null) {
      final bytes = base64Decode(base64Image);
      final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final imageFile = File('${appDir.path}/myImage.jpg');
      await imageFile.writeAsBytes(bytes);
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = imageFile;
      });
      return _imageFile;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  **Getting the value of imageFile here**

        Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        child: FutureBuilder<File?>(
                          future: _imageFuture,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return CircularProgressIndicator();
                            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                            } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
                              return Text('No image available');
                            } else {
                              File imageFile = snapshot.data!;
                              return CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 40,
                                backgroundImage: imageFile != null
                                    ? FileImage(imageFile!)
                                    : null,
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
)
```